# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'seller_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel, laravel-controller

```
       $product = new Product([
        'productName' => $request->productName,
        'quantity' => $request->quantity,
        'weight' => $request->weight,
        'boxes' => $request->boxes,
        'MRP' => $request->MRP,
        'costprice' =>$request->costprice,
        'productDescription' =>$request->productDescription,
        'seller_id' => $request->user('seller')->id,
        'category_id' => $request->category
    ]);

      $product->save();
```

> I have provided values to the product table but still it is showing this error SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'seller_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `products` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2021-12-30 13:35:47, 2021-12-30 13:35:47))

Comment: Can you dump `$request->user('seller')`? Also, it seems it's only inserting the automatic created/updated dates, and during that insertion is when it's complaining about the lack of a default for `seller_id`. This implies that `$product` is not taking on all those properties you've passed into the constructor. You could try to set those properties instead outside the constructor, like `$product->boxes = $request->boxes;` etc.

Comment: seems you are missing fields in `$fillable` on the model

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
  $product = Product::create([
    'productName' => $request->productName,
    'quantity' => $request->quantity,
    'weight' => $request->weight,
    'boxes' => $request->boxes,
    'MRP' => $request->MRP,
    'costprice' =>$request->costprice,
    'productDescription' =>$request->productDescription,
    'seller_id' => $request->user('seller')->id,
    'category_id' => $request->category
]);
```

`$product` should be saved now. Assuming your `$request->user('seller')->id` actually has data, and assuming your attributes you are filling out are all `fillable`. [mass assignment docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)